# How to get an Image from Harddrive into an Bufferdimage in java

Tags: graphics2d

currently me and some other people of my team are trying to build a navigational Application for a studentsproject. we are working with the JXMapKit, and want to set an other randerer for the waypoints on the map, therefore a methode is needed which useses Graphics2D to display image(i at least i belief the methode does that with this Object). So this is the Problem: how can i get an normal Image from my Harddrive into this Graphics2D Object? I read something about that i need a Bufferedimage but that didn't helped me much.
I someone gets the Point in what i mean, because me english is, friendly spoken not the best^^

neverless, i hope someone can help me with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ImageIO.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29) like this:

```
String pathToMyFile = "C:\image.jpg";
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(pathToMyImageFile));
```

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied File with an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently registered. The File is wrapped in an ImageInputStream. If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.

Then you can use the [drawImage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) function of your Graphics2D object:

```
int x,y = 10; //the coorinates where to draw the image
graphics2D.drawImage(image, x, y, null)
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem is, that i have to cover the Bufferdimage with a graphics2D Object or something like that, because the methode i need to paint my Waypoints on the map has the signature:

Comment: paintWaypoint(Graphics2D arg0, JXMapViewer arg1, Waypoint arg2).

I thought that the Graphics2D-object named in the methods signature is the image painted on the JXMapViewer, or do i have a wrong picture of how this methode works in my mind?

Comment: ahhh ok forget it, i had a thinking mistake, the graphics2D objects is only als reference for the paintmethode needed